# How to add an image to an archived page from single

Tags: php, wordpress

There is an archive page and a singe page for Custom Post Type. On a single page, I display an image using ACF. How can I display it on the archive page?

```js
// single post img
<div class = "speaker_img" >
  <img src = "<?php the_field('speaker_img'); ?>" >
</div>


//archive page
<?php
  $args = array(  
  'post_type' => 'speakers',);
     $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
         $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="#">
       <div class="speaker-img">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/speaker-1.png"> </div>
         <div class="speaker-name">
          <p>
           <?php the_title(); ?>
            </p>
             </div>
              <div class="speaker-city">
               <p>
              Fribourg
            </p>
          </div>
        </a></li> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What we sometimes do is create an [ACF Options page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/) with each archive that we want to support and set the images there

Comment: Is it possible to display an image for single and archive pages without ACF?

Comment: Sure. Set a featured image on an arbitrary page and use that.